# How to write POST / PUT requests using RestFixture

Tags: api, rest, post, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I am trying to use smartrics-RestFixture-3.0-bin.zip for **POST** request but it's failing for some reason. Looks like a service problem itself but as I am learning Fitnees, not sure if anything is wrong with the Test as well.

Can anyone please share some details, or example for POST rest request using RestFixture/Wiki format using Demo REST APIs - http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/

**My wiki based TC looks like below - (I am trying to add Customer data with ID = 20)**

```html
'''Trying to add customer 20 entry'''
!| smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture.FitRestFixture | http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/ |
| setBody | <CUSTOMER xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><ID>20</ID><FIRSTNAME>Anne1</FIRSTNAME><LASTNAME>Miller1</LASTNAME><STREET>201 Upland Pl.</STREET><CITY>Lyon1</CITY></CUSTOMER> |
| POST    | /20| 200 | | |
```

**I am getting below Error:**

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.26 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.26</h3></body></html>
```

Please suggest. thanks!

***Updated: 6 April 2015***

I was trying to add new CUSTOMER entry using POST method which was incorrect, I should have used PUT method. Today when I tried using PUT method to add new CUSTOMER entry, I got same error  :(..

Looks like a problem with WEB Service only.

Answer (score 1):

Is the service working normally, do you get a different response if you send the same body to it some other way? (When I send your body to the same url I get the same error.)

The error seems to suggest that the service you are calling is broken. Sometimes this can also be the result of incorrect usage.

As it stands your question seems to have less to do with FitNesse and more with the service you are using.

Comment: Thanks Fried for replying. I also think that service has some problem.. not sure as it is a public service and really don't know its status. 

Do you think that the Table or the way Test is written is correct ? 

Wanted to know if anything wrong with the Test / Data or the way it has created? Please comment. Thanks!

Comment: The test table and its structure look OK because the request reaches correctly the server. Retry by enclosing the content of the setBody in !- -! : |setBody| !- <CUSTOMER .... -! | to make sure that no characters in the payload are incorrectly escaped. You may also want to turn logs on and observe the output console where the actual HTTP request / respose are printed.

Comment: Table looks quite OK. I tried sending the same body (using my own fixture see https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/wiki/4.-XmlHttpTest-Examples) and got the same response

Comment: Do I have to use PUT to add new entry into the DB not POST right ?

Comment: @smartrics if I try to enclose Body with !- -! then  I get - "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ()" and without enclosing I get same as mentioned in question - "The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request."

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error before I added setHeaders section to my wiki.
Try this after setBody:

| setHeaders|Content-Type: application/xml|

Hope this helps.